# How can I limit the bandwidth of apt-mirror?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package-management, apt, mirror

I need to make a once off mirror of all the Ubuntu apt repository (for the record it's because I'm sending it to Kenya (see [here](http://blog.technomancy.org/2009/11/27/what-would-you-put-on-a-harddrive-going-to-kenya) and [here](http://ubuntungo.wordpress.com/2009/11/26/what-would-you-put-on-a-harddrive-going-out-to-africa/)).

I did it before and used [apt-mirror](http://apt-mirror.sourceforge.net/), and that does exactly what I want. However now I want to do it slowly, so I want to limit the bandwidth it uses to download. Is there any easy way to do it? Any magic apt configuration setting?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After I looked at the source code for apt-mirror, I discovered that apt-mirror has inbuilt abilities to limit the bandwith rate.

Just put:

```
set limit_rate 50k
```

In your mirror.list file and it will pass that into wget. However that limit is per thread. So if you have 10 threads, this will be 50k * 10 = 500k. This feature is not documentated at all.

Comment: From the limited testing I have done (using nload), it appears that this sets in KiloBytes/s instead of KiloBits, so one may want to divide by 8. E.g if you want to limit to 1 mbit per thread, use a value of 125k

Answer (score 6):

Dan Carley are right about perl wrapper. But smarter way - edit *~/.wgetrc* (user specific config) or */etc/wgetrc* (system-wide config)
and add option

```
limit-rate = 50k # or your limit rate
```

Comment: Yep, good point. My only small reservation would be forgetting that you've put it at some later date.

Answer (score 4):

Since `apt-mirror` is just a Perl wrapper for `wget`. You could edit the source code to utilise the `wget` flag [`--limit-rate`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-rate_002c-limit-46) which takes a download speed expressed in bytes, kilobytes or megabytes.

Depending upon your understanding of Perl, you could either do this the right way, by adding a new configuration option and ideally submitting a patch back to the author. Or you can just hardcode the value that you need for the moment.